# Shell script printing when I don't want it to

Tags: linux, shell

What I'm trying to do is take certain actions only if the last line contains the characters TRL:

```
TRL= tail -1 $1|cut -c1-3

if [ "$TRL"=="TRL"];
then ##some commands
```

The issue is that the variable TRL is printing in stdout, which is undesirable. How can I prevent this?

Comment: Note that `[ "$TRL"=="TRL"]` calls `[` with a single argument, e.g. `'TRL==TRL]'`, which is certainly not what you want. I recommend you go through a quick Bash tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try instead capturing the output of that tail | cut command as:

```
TRL=$(tail -1 $1|cut -c1-3)
```

Comment: Thank you, that did it! I appreciate your quick response.